# Find "rooms" from lines and points drawings

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, geometry, polygon

### Background

I am working on a room drawing tool application, where user can draw walls to form rooms. However, I couldn't figure out how to detect new rooms in a working and efficient way.
Every room contains the following items:

- List of points (point stores connecting walls)
- List of walls (wall stores head and tail points)
- Floor

#### First room

[image: First room]

The `First room` is detected upon walls enclosed, collecting all points by hopping through walls until the first point is found again, so that all points are sorted clockwise as well. [A,B,C,D][1,2,3,4]

#### Question

Now the user may draw new walls, it is easy to split rooms if they draw the wall inside the room. But, if they draw the walls outside the room, it is confusing to find the route to detect the new room.

For example:
[New room](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Sus.png)
Let's say the user draw a new room in bottom-left, starting from new point E (between D,A on wall 4), ending in point I (between C,D on wall 3)
If I use the same method as detecting the first room, abnormal results may appear. Therefore, I will need a new method or fix the old one.

To detect the first room, I coded like this:

```
void DetectClosing(Point endPoint) // Try to find closed walls to generate floor
    {
//To-do: detect expand new room or split room
//Detect from onDrag, inside = split, outside = expand
        if (floors.Count == 0)
        {
            List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();
            Point target = endPoint;
            Points.Add(target);
            Room room = new Room();
            Wall walltarget = target.walls[0];
            room.walls.Add(walltarget);
            while (true)
            {
                foreach (var item in walltarget.points) //Find the next point from current wall
                {
                    if (item == target) continue; //Wall has two points, skip self
                    target = item;
                    print("Next point");
                    break;
                }
                if (target == wallPoints[0]) break; //End of while-loop upon reaching the first point again

                Points.Add(target);

                foreach (var item in target.walls) //Find the next wall from new point, must edit
                {
                    if (item == walltarget) continue; //Point has two or more walls, skip self
                    walltarget = item;
                    print("Next wall");
                    break;
                }
            }

            room.points = MeshManager.Instance.points = wallPoints;
            room.floor = MeshManager.Instance.CreateFloor();
        }
    }
```

From observe, the new room should be [E,D,I,H,G,F][9,10,8,7,6,5]
(Points and walls may have different orders but should be sorted clockwise)
And first room is added with point E,I and wall 9,10.

However, I am confused to get the route to detect the room. As we can see point E and I have 3 walls, that means the room could be both [E,D,I,H,G,F] or [E,A,B,C,I,H,G,F,E]

The method must get room [E,D,I,H,G,F] and detecting new rooms correctly.

Comment: Please describe the detailed process of drawing walls. What data can the program obtain after the user finishes drawing? Can this process be changed?

Comment: It is actually a question about how to find rooms correctly via any method. Original method is keep hopping points until we hit the starting point again, but this method doesn't work if more rooms' going to be drawn, as the path may be wrong when there are 3 walls on a point. So all process can be added/changed, but keep the following data:

Comment: class Room(){
  List<Point> points;
  List<Wall> walls;
  Floor floor //dismiss this one, useless in this question
}
class Wall(){
  Point head, tail;
}
class Point(){
  List<Wall> walls;
}

Comment: Are walls a vertical/horizontal line between 2 points or a polyline ? Is there constraints when creating a wall, e.g. head point cannot be inside an existing room if tail point is outside ? Are wall intersections allowed ? what about opened passages, i.e head point on a another wall and tail point only connected to head point ?

Comment: Thanks for comment. A single wall between two points is a straight line. New room creation is only triggered when: Head point(draw-start) of first new wall is hitting a point or an old wall(wall is split in this case) & All new walls are outside the existing room & Tail point(draw-end) of last new wall is hitting a point(old points only) or an old wall(wall is split in this case, new-drawn walls are not allowed). Therefore, if the starting head point is drawn outside the room, it will consider we are drawing another first room, the method must not apply. No wall intersections allowed.

Comment: The question is showing the First room image only :( There is a new room image under it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be useful to consider *wall side* as the main element instead of points and walls.

We can define orientation of a wall side - the direction we have to go to have the wall on the left.

Every point connects many pairs of wall sides and the we just need to split the set of wall sides into connected loops.

So:

1. For every point you order walls adjacent to it by angle (clockwise, counter-clockwise, doesn't really matter) and construct wall sides connections (from-to)
2. Take any unprocessed wall side and go along connections until returning back - that will be a room, all traversed wall sides are marked as processed
3. Repeat #2 until there are any unprocessed wall sides

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your comment that an existing wall is systematically divided in 2 parts when the head/trail point of a new wall is located on the old wall, we can skip a first step that consist in splitting walls in multiple parts so that intersections are always at walls extremities.

- The algorithm will consist to start from top-left point P1 of all
  unprocessed walls.
- Consider the a virtual point P0 located at the
  left of P1 to initialize the current vector [Pi-1->Pi].
- Among all points (walls extremities) connected to Pi, determine the point Pi so that the angle between [Pi->Pi-1] and [Pi->Pi+1] is the minimum.
- Mark the points Pi as processed and globally processed and mark the oriented walls, i.e. [Pi->Pi+1]
- Iterate the operation until you find a point Pi belonging to the current room (i.e. Pi=Pj with 0<j<i), what gives you a room.

Loop on all process to search other rooms :

- starting point is an unprocessed point,
- ignore already processed oriented walls when searching Pi+1 (note that a wall with opposite orientation needs to be considered).

Comment: Will this find the middle room in a square divided by walls into 3x3 rooms? (in case it would happen to handle the outer rooms first)

Comment: @maxim1000 : In initial loop, the algorithm will  find the outer room , marking all points of the contour as processed. Then searching an unprocessed point to start the search of a new room, the process will identify the inner room.